# Encrypting data in order to store in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, encryption

I use VS2010, C#, SQL Server 2008 to develop my ASP.NET web app. I'm searching for a function that can encrypt my data before storing it into SQL Server tables, I had recently used a function which performed it, this function had a key, that was used for decrypting data, but I cannot find it again!

What are my options for encryption? Is there any robust and meanwhile easy to use function or approach?

Comment: Do you mean options for decrypting the data you lost the key for?  Or alternative options for the future?  Also, what are you encrypting, and why?  *[If it's passwords, you can store the hashed value, and hash what users enter, then compare, thus never needing to decrypt. If it's data, why do you feel the need to encrypt rather than rely on your sql server's security and/or encryption?  And where would you securely store your key(s)?]*

Comment: In fact I'm performing this job for someone else, and I'm asked to do some extra security operations, I'm just trying to display him some functions, of course I know what I'm going to do would not be technically wise

Comment: Without a bit more context information the answer will be a bit generic.  What are you trying to achieve?  Why?  What doesn't the existing SQL Server security already provide?  It *feels* that you're re-inventing the wheel and don't need to do this, but  more full picture would be needed to give any specific advice.

Comment: Yes you are right, I think I can use built in features, I should study more about them, thanks for your description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in [transparent data encryption feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) in SQL Server 2008.